# Maximal factorization of finite simple groups and no extra intermediate

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-combinatorics, computational-group-theory

The book [The maximal factorizations of the finite simple groups and their automorphism groups](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1016353) (by Martin W. Liebeck, Cheryl E. Praeger and Jan Saxl) provides a classification of all the triples $(G,A,B)$ such that:

- $G$ is a finite simple group,
- $A$ and $B$ are maximal subgroups of $G$,
- $AB=G$.

**Question**: What is the classification with the following *additional* assumption?

- No extra intermediate: if $(A \cap B) < H < G$ then $H \in \{A,B\}$.

*Remark*: by GAP computation, below is the classification for $|G|<2\cdot 10^6$:

- $(A_6, \ A_5, \ A_5)$,
- $(A_8, \ A_7, \ 2^3:A_1(7))$,
- $(M_{12}, \ M_{11}, \ M_{11})$,
- $(C_2(2^2), \ A_1(2^4):2, \ A_1(2^4):2)$,
- $(C_3(2), \ A_8:2, \ ^2A_2(3^2):2)$.

---

This post was inspired by an exchange with Pablo Spiga.

Comment: @YCor  The inequalities should be strict, otherwise we can have $H= A \cap B$ or $G$.

Comment: I think that $C = A \cap B$ is self-normalizing in $G$ in your situation. Since $G = AB$ and $A,B$ are proper, we know that $A$ and $B$ are not $G$-conjugate. But $N_{G}(A \cap B)$ permutes the maximal subgroups which contain $A \cap B$, so must normalize both $A$ and $B.$ Since $A$ and $B$ are each maximal but not normal, it follows that $N_{G}(A \cap B) \leq A \cap B.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson how do we know A and B are not conjugate, i.e., A = gBg^{-1}

Comment: @JohnJiang: Assume the existence of $g \in G$ such that $A=gBg^{-1}$. Now $g=ab$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ because $G=AB$. So $A = abBb^{-1}a^{-1} = aBa^{-1}$, $A=a^{-1}Aa = B$. It follows that $A=B=G$, contradiction with $A,B$ proper subgroups.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to write and ask the authors of the paper?

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the wrong edit.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux thanks!

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I struggled another 20 minutes but can’t figure out why N_G A\cap B must normalize A and B. Please help again?

Comment: @JohnJiang: let $g \in N_G(A\cap B)$ and $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $A \cap B$. Then $A \cap B = g(A \cap B)g^{-1} \le gMg^{-1}$ which is also a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $A \cap B$. So by the "no extra intermediate" assumption we must have $gAg^{-1} \in \{A,B\}$, but we already know that $A$ and $B$ are not $G$-conjugate, so $gAg^{-1} = A$. It follows that $A$ is a normal subgroup of $K=\langle N_G(A\cap B) , A \rangle$. But $A$ is a maximal subgroup, so $K \in \{A,G\}$. But $G$ is simple, so $K = A$ which means that  $N_G(A\cap B) \le A$. Idem, $N_G(A\cap B) \le B$.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux oh sorry I missed the no extra intermediate assumption.

Comment: @JohnJiang : Sebastian Palcoux answered your question, but here is a different explanation : If $G = AgAg^{-1}$, then $G = Gg = AgA.$ If $g \in A$ we have $G = A$, a contradiction. If $g \not \in A$, then $A$ is disjoint from $AgA$, contrary to $G = AgA$.

Comment: I don't know of such a classification but the original memoir by Liebeck, Praeger and Saxl often determines if $A\cap B$ is maximal in $A$ and $B$. This is necessary for your condition.

Comment: @MichaelGiudici: Thanks! Can you cite a page where it is written?

Comment: There is a column on the tables which indicates when $A\cap B$ is maximal in $A$ and $A$ is almost simple. Similarly, for $B$. There is further information hidden throughout the proof for each individual factorisation.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I sent you the answers of the authors by email. Is the classification provided in their book available on GAP?
It would be very helpful for answering my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a classification being available on GAP. Anyway, I don't know the answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I mean a function which returns all the maximal factorizations (upto equivalence) of a given finite simple group, not by computing them but by using the classification provided by the aforesaid book (published in 1990).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much it contributes to answering the question, but it is true that if $G$ is a non-Abelian finite simple group which admits the factorization 
$G = AB$ with $A,B$ maximal subgroups with the additional property that $A \cap B$ is properly contained in no proper subgroup other than $A$ or $B$, then one of the following occurs:

i) $|A \cap B|$ has at least two distinct prime divisors.

ii) $A \cap B$ is  a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G.$

iii) $A \cap B$ is  a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G.$

Proof: Suppose that i) does not hold. Then $A \cap B$ is a (non-trivial) $p$-group for some prime $p.$ 
(As I remarked in comments) $A \cap B$ is self-normalizing in $G$ because $N_{G}(A \cap B)$ permutes the subgroups containing $A \cap B$ by conjugation, but $A$ and $B$ are not conjugate (since $G = AB$). Hence $N_{G}(A \cap B) \leq N_{G}(A) \cap N_{G}(B) = A \cap B$ since $G$ is simple and $A,B$ are maximal.

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ containing $A \cap B.$ If $A \cap B < P,$ then $N_{P}(A \cap B) > A \cap B$, a contradiction. Hence $A \cap B = P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ for some prime $p$.

If $p \geq 5,$ then a theorem of G. Glauberman implies that $G \neq O^{p}(G)$ since $N_{G}(P) = P,$ contrary to the simplicity of $G$.  Hence $p \leq 3,$ and either ii) or iii) holds.